# The register of Odette's language

Tags: vocabulaire, littérature

This is from Proust:

> – Mais elle a l’air d’une ouvreuse, d’une vieille concierge, darling ! Ça, une marquise ! Je ne suis pas marquise, mais il faudrait me payer bien cher pour me faire sortir nippée comme ça !
> Elle ne comprenait pas que Swann habitât l’hôtel du quai d’Orléans que, sans oser le lui avouer, elle trouvait indigne de lui. Certes, elle avait la prétention d’aimer les « antiquités » et prenait un air ravi et fin pour dire qu’elle adorait passer toute une journée à « bibeloter », à chercher « du bric-à-brac », des choses « du temps ».
> Bien qu’elle s’entêtât dans une sorte de point d’honneur (et semblât pratiquer quelque précepte familial) en ne répondant jamais aux questions et en ne « rendant pas de comptes » sur l’emploi de ses journées, elle parla une fois à Swann d’une amie qui l’avait invitée et chez qui tout était « de l’époque ». Mais Swann ne put arriver à lui faire dire quelle était cette époque. Pourtant, après avoir réfléchi, elle répondit que c’était « moyenâgeux ». Elle entendait par là qu’il y avait des boiseries.

Obviously a lot of Odette's words are in scare quotes.  The question is why? Her status is a woman of the demi-monde but is she still not speaking like she is supposed to?  I'm guessing as a member of the demi-monde you're supposed to speak at a higher level than a peasant or a street walker but not higher than a titled noble.  It's difficult to translate this sort of thing.  Most of her words in scare quotes are translated into expressions in English which are somewhat low-class but still this sort of thing is hard to convey. For examples, we have bric-a-brac in English but it's used so rarely that's not really associated with any kind of status.  (I looked up the exact numbers and in English the expression is used 15 times for every 5000 times in French).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the reported speech in quotes reflects more of a vague and improper use of words than a very low language register. Her choice of terms is not sharp enough to be that of a perfectly educated woman who has dealt a lot with refined interiors in her life.

Saying something "*is moyenâgeux*" instead of "has *boiseries*" is a perfect example of that - not necessarily vulgar but mostly tasteless, uncultured, unrefined, approximate.